# Does Ubuntu support working with compressed Windows files?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, ntfs, compression

In Windows 10 pro, there is an option "Compress this drive to save disk space". If I were to enable that option, will Ubuntu be able to open the files like normal? And is there any side effect in using it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am very new to Ubuntu, and I don't understand any of the link all of you have sent. But, let me clarify, if I were to enable that option and window compressed all the files, will Ubuntu be able to open and use that files like normal?

Comment: According to [https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/compression.html](https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/compression.html) yes, ntfs-3g supports all current NTFS compression methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Linux supports transparent compression of NTFS drives.

See:

- [Is it a good idea to use compressed NTFS filesystem on an external harddisk?](https://superuser.com/questions/257267/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-compressed-ntfs-filesystem-on-an-external-harddisk)

  > Yes, it is possible to access it from Liunx
- [NTFS-3G Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G)

  > Transparent compression is supported
- [Discussion on ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9121138)

  > File system compression is just more of a headache than it's worth.
- [The New NTFS Linux Driver Updated With Better Compression Handling](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NTFS3-v14-Compression)

  > with this latest iteration of the NTFS3 patches, the compression support is more full-featured in dealing with file-system compressed files. NTFS supports per-file compression as well as drive-level compression
- [NTFS3G - Using Transparently Compressed Files](https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/compression.html)

  > Currently reading compressed files is supported by all ntfs-3g versions. Creating new compressed files, clearing contents, and appending data to existing compressed files are supported since ntfs-2009.11.14.

It seems, that it's quite well-supported and side-effects are the same as in Windows: Depending on what is the bottle-neck on your machine, you may notice lower performance.

If your bottleneck is CPU/RAM you will notice it more, but if your bottleneck is I/O, it theoretically might even improve your performance as less data has to be written.